# WPF DataGrid repeat Headers in all rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

My requirement is to display headers of DataGrid in following format instead of normal grid.

[image]

My code for normal DataGrid as follows:

```
<DataGrid Margin="7.208,8,7.888,8" Grid.Row="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="gridOrder" BorderBrush="#FFB38807" Background="#FFEDEDEC" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFB38807" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFB38807" SelectionChanged="gridOrder_SelectionChanged" CanUserAddRows="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns> 
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order ID" Binding="{Binding orderid}" /> 
      <DataGridTextColumn Header=" Order Time" Binding="{Binding orderTime}" /> 
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Status" Binding="{Binding orderStatus}" /> 
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Can any one help me out for this kind of requirement.

Comment: What is your question or problem? What isn't working?

Comment: This is question, how to display the datagrid in above format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="OrderId : "/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderId}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="OrderTime : "/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderTime}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="OrderStatus : "/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderStatus}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```